# Button alignment just below a multi-line EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multi-line EditText, followed by a button below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    style="@style/OuterLayout.InnerLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineBelowTitleBar">

....couple of other textviews.........

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/problem_details_title"
        android:text="What can we help you with?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_textSize_layout_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line2"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/problem_details_title">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/problem_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top"/>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    style="@style/LongButton"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

When we first open up the activity, the button should be shown at the bottom, therefore, I used:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

As soon as the `EditText` gains focus and the keyboard pops-up, everything should scroll up leaving me enough space to write. But what I'm getting is this:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the cursor hides behind the button. What I want is a little bit of space between edittext and the button. Using margins didn't help.

Comment: if you align the button on bottom of the last textview?

Comment: Have you tried with *andorid:fillViewPort=true* in *ScrollView*. And also use *adjustPan* or *adjustResize* in manifest for that *activity*.

Comment: @jaydroider, I was already using adjustResize. When I tried `adjustPan`, I could see the full cursor as well as the text I was typing. But, the *Continue* button was still at the bottom of the screen behind the soft-keyboard.

Comment: @Tony: When I first open up the activity, I should see the button at the bottom of the screen. The last edittext doesn't end anywhere near the bottom. Therefore, I cannot align the button at the bottom of the last textview.

Comment: make scrollview as parent container and there is no need of adding edittext in scrollview. You can use linear layout for this behaviour too.

Comment: @Prag'sシ still not getting the desired behavior.

Comment: The **Continue** button doesn't show up when the EditText is in focus. It's behind the soft-keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `android:layout_above` property of relative layout you can align the layout above other layout or `android:layout_below` with your button if button is also part of relative layout.

Comment: At the beginning of the activity, the button should be right at the bottom of the screen. If I use `layout_below` or `layout_above`, the button won't align at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can you try to put  margin_top to button and set adjustPan or adjustResize in manifest for this activity.

Comment: I was already using adjustResize. I tried adjustPan too, and it well shows the cursor and the text I'm writing. But the button couldn't be seen then. Even after setting margin_top, the button is not seen. I guess alignParentBottom is overriding any margins assigned?